# Video cropping tool

Tags: windows, video-editing

I created a video to demonstrate how to do something in OneNote, and now I need to insert it in my reference app.  The video fills my entire screen, which isn't optimal for my app because only 165x110 pixels are actually involved in the video - the rest is a blank white background.  Now, I need to find out how to crop this video down to the essential pixel size.  If this cannot be done, I could create a .gif, but I would prefer to just crop my video.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any decent video editor would have this feature.

E.g. you can use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BTfJ.jpg)
- Has a GUI.
- Can [crop](http://www.screenvirtuoso.com/virtualdub-video-cropping.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I really like this, especially the way I could just run it without an installation.  Unfortunately, I need to convert my .mp4 to a .mpeg now.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/ffinputdriver/ ?

Answer (score 10):

If you prefer using a CLI, you can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)
- Allows to [crop](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/4563/2117): `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4`
- Is CLI so you can batch.

Comment: There is very little I haven't managed to do with ffmpeg. The learning curve is pretty steep, but it's very much worth learning if you do lots of video editing.

Answer (score 5):

[XMediaRecode](http://www.xmedia-recode.de/download.html) will do this for you. It is a video and audio transcoding program that works on Windows. It also supports a lot of different file types such as WMV, MP4, MP3, 3GP, Matroska and more. Additionally it has a GUI and is Freeware.
[image: Image of XMediaRecode cropping MrMaker]

Answer (score 3):

If you have issues installing the proper codec on VirtualDub, you can use [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/):

- free and open source
- binaries for win32/win64
- Go to Video > Filters > Crop

[image]